# Mono C# evaluator - redirect script console output

Tags: c#, mono

I'm using the `Mono.CSharp.Evaluator` class to run C# scripts, and would like to use `Console.WriteLine()` or `Debug.WriteLine()` statements in my scripts. Is there any way to redirect such output back to the "hosting" application?

Code snippet:-

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var reportWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
var reportPrinter = new ConsoleReportPrinter(reportWriter);
var compilerContext = new CompilerContext(settings, reportPrinter);
var evaluator = new Evaluator(compilerContext);

evaluator.Run("Console.WriteLine(""Hello!"");");
```

Given its name I hoped the `ConsoleReportPrinter` might have been designed for this purpose, but the only time I see anything here (actually the StringBuilder it writes to) is to report syntax errors in the script.

Answer (score 1):

After further digging I came up with a solution...

The `Evaluator` utilises an "interactive base class" that (I think) acts as a wrapper around the script being executed (this class is exposed via the `Evaluator.InteractiveBaseClass` property).

Looking at the source this defaults to a class called `InteractiveBase` which has a *static* TextWriter property called "Output", whose value defaults to "Console.Out". What I did was assign my own Stringwriter to this, which allows me to capture output to my existing StringBuilder:

```
var outputStringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
InteractiveBase.Output = _outputStringWriter;
```

This still doesn't let me use `Console.WriteLine()` from within the script, but a script *can* access any property or method of the "interactive base class", so in my script I can call:

```
Output.WriteLine("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

While injecting my own print function as local variable I discovered that there already is a global method `print(object value)` you can call which writes to std out.